# How and when does a pointer change the address it's pointing to (linked list example)?

Tags: c++, linked-list, c++17

I've been taking a course and I know how a linked list works, I've made several of them by myself as practice and they all work fine, however, I came across one that wasn't as obvious to me and took me a bit to understand.

When you have a node class where the constructor takes arguments to set the value and link vs when you have a constructor that does NOT take arguments.
Example: `Node(const val = 0, Node* ptr = nullptr){link = ptr; value = val;}` vs `Node(){}`

How do the two implementations differ below? assume `head_ptr` points to `nullptr`

```
void list_head_insert(node* head_ptr, const value){
    head_ptr = new node(value, head_ptr);
    return;
}

// yes i know you need to account for more than 1 node being there if there is
// assume there isn't and this is the first and only so far

void list_head_insert(node* head_ptr, const value){
    head_ptr = new node();
    head_ptr->set_value(value);
    head_ptr->set_link(nullptr);
    return;
}
```

in the first, is the `new` node created first and then head_ptr points to it after or does it point to it first before inserting values via arguments?

edit: i forgot to add `&` to pass `head_ptr` by reference in the argument, but i see why it should be there.

Comment: You passed the head_ptr by value meaning it makes a copy and passes the copy leaving the original unmodified. `void list_head_insert(node* head_ptr, const value){` should be `void list_head_insert(node* & head_ptr, const value){` if you want to pass by reference.

Comment: A pointer changes its value (address it's pointing to) when you assign it a new value.  This may be one of those situations where you suspect it's more complicated than it actually is.  `new node()` happens first, which gets the object all set up in memory at some address.  Then `head_ptr = xxx` will replace the value of `head_ptr` with the value of `xxx`, in this case `xxx` is the address returned by `new node()`.

Comment: Right hand side of `=` operator is evaluated first, so `new node(value, head_ptr)` is created with the original value of `head_ptr` and then `head_ptr` is modified to point to the newly created `node`. But, as comment above noticed, neither function will show the result to the outside world.

Comment: `void list_head_insert(node *head_ptr, const value) { head_ptr = new node(); head_ptr->set_value(value); head_ptr->set_link(nullptr); return; }` is a memory leak.  After the function returns, you have no references to the memory that was allocated by `new node();`.  At the very least, one would expect to see `return head_ptr`.  Also, since the value passed in is never used, I would expect `head_ptr` to simply be a local variable rather than an ignored argument.